# adding Multiple subviews efficiently on a scroll view

Tags: ios, view

If we need to add multiple views say - a tableview, a mapview and 2 or 3 more views on a single scrollable screen, then what would be most efficient way to do it ?
And will it be suitable for an app from the point of memory management?
Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it programmatically: just add them in your viewDidLoad (or possibly your viewWillAppear) methods.

```
- (void) viewWillLoad
{
    self.myScrollView = [[UIScollView alloc] init];
    //Configure scrollview here (frame, contentsize, contentoffset...etc)

    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    //Configure table here (frame...etc)

    [self.myScrollView addSubview:tableView];
    //Continue adding other subviews here
}
```

Or you can do it visually using storyboards. Just drag the views that you want onto your storyboard and then cntrl drag to your .m or .h files.

And yes, iOS is designed for displaying multiple views at once.  It is suitable.

Comment: so is it memory efficient.I mean it will not create any memory issue adding so many views on a single scrollview ?

Comment: Yes.  This will work fine.  As I stated above, iOS is designed to handle multiple views on the screen at once.  The only time you'd have to worry is if you wanted to but like 100 views in a scrollview.  Even then, it would probably work, it would just be sluggish